# Gnome-shell process has huge CPU usage

Tags: gnome-shell, cpu-load

My pc was fine yesterday. It was on for about 20 hours and went to sleep mode couple times during that. I noticed my pc was lagging, opened task manager and saw gnome-shell using 4GBs of ram and using 40% of my i5-4690k CPU. It normally uses about 1-7%. I've tried rebooting without success.

Comment: Google Chrome seems to be causing this cpu-usage. Hasn't done it before.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by uninstalling amdgpu via `./amdgpu-uninstall` in the file directory. Which I do not remember but it can be found by searching for "amdgpu" in files.